# Подматрицы прямоугольного матрица

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить.
Дано A прямоугольная матрица.

Написать функцию Solution,который найдет количество неповторяющийся 2x2 подматрицы в матрице A.
Например в матрице А количество неповторяющийся 2x2 подматриц 6

A = [[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[1,2,3],[2,2,1]]

```
 - 1,2
   2,2
 - 2,1
   2,2
 - 2,2 
   2,2
 - 2,2 
   1,2
 - 2,2 
   2,3
 - 2,3 
   2,1
```

**Мой Код**

```
    function solution(x){
    let arr = []
    console.log(x)
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length-1; i++) {
            let line = []
        for (var j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
            line.push(x[i][j],x[i][j+1],x[i+1][j],x[i+1][j+1])
            arr.push(line)
            if (x[i+1]==x.length-1) {
                break
            }
        }
    } return arr.length
    }

    [[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[1,2,3],[2,2,1]] //6
    [[9,9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9,9]] //1
    [[3]] //0
    [[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]] // 0
```

Comment: Молодец. В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: который найдет количество неповторяющийся 2x2 подматрицы в матрице A

Comment: не получается ни как,у меня 4,1,0,0 ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[i+1] == x.length-1` ? `x[i+1]` — это следующая строка матрицы (массив). `x.length - 1` — какое-то число. Сравниваете массив с числом (+1 причина давать переменным более естественные названия).

У вас просят количество уникальных матриц `2x2`. Тут полезно заметить, что по условию задачи не обязательно собирать именно матрицы 2х2. Главное научиться как-то сравнивать их. Поэтому можно сразу хранить в массиве не матрицы, а представляющие их строки, которые удобнее будет проверять на уникальность:

```js
Test().forEach(mtx => console.log( solution(mtx) ) );

function solution(matrix) {
  let arr = [];
  
  for( let i = 0; i < matrix.length - 1; i++ ) {
    let row_this = matrix[i];
    let row_next = matrix[i + 1];
    for( let j = 0; j < row_this.length - 1; j++ ) {
      let _2x2 = String(
        [
          [row_this[j], row_this[j + 1]],
          [row_next[j], row_next[j + 1]]
        ]
      );
      
      if( arr.includes( _2x2 ) ) continue;
      
      arr.push( _2x2 );      
    }    
  }
  
  return arr.length;
}

/***/
function Test() {
  return [
    [[1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1]],  //6
    [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9]], //1
    [[3]], //0
    [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] // 0
  ]
}
```

P.s.

```js
console.log( [1, 2] === [1, 2] ); // false; 
// Хранят одинаковые данные, но это два разных массива.

console.log( JSON.stringify( [1, 2] ) === JSON.stringify( [1, 2] ) ); // true;

console.log( JSON.stringify( [[1, 2], [3, 4]] ) ); // "[[1,2],[3,4]]"
// Для данной задачи сохранение скобок не играет роли.

console.log( String( [[1, 2], [3, 4]] ) ); // "1,2,3,4"
// этого достаточно для проверки на уникальность.
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное